# GLIBC_2.7 not found

Tags: centos, glibc, libc

I am getting the following error when trying to run several executables:

```
/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by .tools/bridge/bridge)
```

I have recently upgraded from CentOS 5.3 to 5.7 (I am required to run these tools on CentOS 5, so I can't upgrade to 6).
I recompiled the whole code but this error still appears.

Has anyone encountered this type of error?

Thanks,
Claudiu

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error means that you built `.tools/bridge/bridge` on a system with `glibc-2.7` (or later), and are trying to run it on a system that has `glibc-2.6` or earlier.

Linux (and most UNIXes) does not support "build on later, run on earlier"; only the reverse scenario is supported.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8846364/50617).

Answer (score -2):

The 'glibc' is not the latest version, and you can try to update glibc package.

```
yum install glibc
```

or

```
yum install glibc-2.7
```