# when import mxnet on CentOS, get: OSError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found

Tags: python, glibc, mxnet

I am trying to import mxnet on a shared cluster, but I encounter errors:

```
import mxnet as mx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ironfs/scratch/carlos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .base import MXNetError
  File "/home/ironfs/scratch/carlos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet/base.py", line 96, in <module>
    _LIB = _load_lib()
  File "/home/ironfs/scratch/carlos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet/base.py", line 88, in _load_lib
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path[0], ctypes.RTLD_LOCAL)
  File "/home/ironfs/scratch/carlos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /home/ironfs/scratch/carlos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet/libmxnet.so)
```

And I am not admin. Can anyone help me to fix that?

Comment: The prebuilt version probably relies on a newer glibc version than is present on your system. Instead of installing from pip / anaconda you should compile mxnet yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! So you suggest that I download mxnet source code and then use cmake to compile it?

Comment: Yes, you can follow the instructions here: http://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/install/index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GLIBC\_2.7 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819554/glibc-2-7-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

the distributed version of mxnet 1.0.0 seems to have been compiled with glibc_2.7, you would need either to compile from source as mentioned by Ieezu (http://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/install/index.html) or upgrade your version of glibc.

`objdump -T libmxnet.so | grep GLIBC_`

`...
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 stdin
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 srand
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.6   __sched_cpucount
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.3.3 pthread_tryjoin_np
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 log10f
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 if_nametoindex
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.7   eventfd
...`