# Can’t make python work in conda environment (GLIBC not found)

Tags: python-3.x, centos, conda, glibc, remote-server

I'm trying to set up a conda environment with python 3.6 on a remote server working on CentOS. The installation goes well, but once I try to execute python I get the following message python: /lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.15' not found. I noticed that for other python version older than 3.4 this doesn't happen.

Given this, I tried installing glibc before python, but after installing python 3.6 and trying to run it, now I get Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Note that I don't have permissions to update conda and that the version the server is using is 4.4.7, so I haven't tried updating it. However, I had previously set an environment without any problem. After I tried to install a package my jupyter notebooks wouldn't work so I removed the environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GLIBC\_2.7 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819554/glibc-2-7-not-found)

Comment: I don’t understand the answer. What would be the new system and the old one. Does that mean the only solution is to update conda?

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the new system and the old one.

The old system -- the remove server running CentOS, has GLIBC that is older than 2.15.

The new system -- the one on which your `Python 3.6` was compiled, used GLIBC-2.15 (or newer).

You need to either find a Python 3.6 build which is targeted to your version of CentOS, or you need to compile one yourself *on a system with GLIBC matching whatever is installed on your remote server*.

P.S. Saying "server running CentOS" is like saying "system running Windows" (i.e. not saying much). *Which version* of CentOS?

Comment: The CentOS version is 6.6 and has GLIBC 2.12

Comment: The CentOS version is 6.6 and has GLIBC 2.12. Sorry for my ignorace, but I still can't understand which are the two systems. The old one is the remote server and the new system would be the conda environment? The weird thing is, when I check the packages installed on the environment it says glibc is 2.19. Thank you for your response.

Comment: The old system is one on which you are trying to run. The new system is the one on which your `Python 3.6` was built (assuming you are downloading it from somewhere).